# JToolBar buttons with different size images-NetBeans

Tags: java, image, swing, user-interface

I'm having problem in my [`JToolBar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toolbar.html). I'm using images of different size.

[image: Squashed GUI]

Tool bar is not looking good.  How can I use different size images in the `JToolbar` buttons?

1. How can I show the button label below each image?
2. How can all the buttons be aligned from the top, left corner?

For example,

```
java.net.URL imageURL2 = cldr.getResource("Images/report2.jpg");
    ImageIcon aceOfDiamonds1 = new ImageIcon(imageURL2);
    btnReport = new JButton(aceOfDiamonds1);
    btnReport.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(49, 43));
    btnReport.addActionListener(this);
    jToolBar1.add(btnReport);
```

Comment: Are the images even the same aspect ratio?  I do not find the screen shot to be very clear.  See the tips in [How do I create screenshots?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99734/how-do-i-create-a-screenshot-to-illustrate-a-post)

Answer (score 2):

> I'm using images of different size.

Resize them.  Either once at time of build (recommended), or at run-time.

> And I want to show the button label below each image

This is close.

`new`[`JButton(String,Icon)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html#JButton%28java.lang.String,%20javax.swing.Icon%29)`;`

Comment: there  is no option to resize the image here know?

Comment: *"there is no option to resize the image here know?"*  Huh?  1) By 'here' are you referring to SO or something else? 2) By 'know' (knowledge) DYM now (time)?

Comment: In this program in java how can i do this? If just ill reduce its size means it will lost its clarity?

Comment: *"In this program in java how can i do this?"* Search SO for 'resize image Java'.  It has been discussed a couple of times before.

Comment: *"If just ill reduce its size means it will lost its clarity?"*  Of course!  But clever programs like Photoshop have ways to hide the carnage and make a decent (understandable) resized image.  That is why I suggest doing it before it gets to the Java program.  Much simpler.  See also the edit to my answer re. the label for the images.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5341/discussion-between-sakthibalaji-and-andrew-thompson)

Answer (score 2):

> And i want to show the button label below to the each image?

With the `setVerticalTextPosition` and `setHorizontalTextPosition` methods of JButton:

```
// Place text below icon
button.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
button.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
```

> How to show all this buttons align from the left top corner

As Andrew Thompson said, the images all have to be the same size.